# Lowest common ancestor in parent/child isa? hierarchy in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lowest-common-ancestor

Let's say we have this parent/child hierarchy:

```
(derive ::integer ::decimal)
(derive ::positive-integer ::integer)
(derive ::long ::integer)
```

What is a Clojure idiomatic to implement a way to find the lowest common ancestor in such a hierarchy? I.e.:

```
(lca ::positive-integer ::long) ; => ::integer
```

My initial thoughts include using a recursive function traversing combinations of `parents` of each argument, but I suspect there probably is a better approach.

My motivation is to use this as a dispatch function for a multimethod that takes 2 arguments and dispatches to the best suited implementation based on the types of the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `ancestors` returns a set, so you'll want to `(require [clojure.set :as s])`.

Now write:

```
(defn lca [h1 h2]
  (let [a1 (into #{} (conj (ancestors h1) h1))
        a2 (into #{} (conj (ancestors h2) h2))
        ac (s/intersection a1 a2)]
    (apply (partial max-key (comp count ancestors)) ac)))
```

Let's try it out!

```
stack-prj.hierarchy> (derive ::integer ::decimal)
nil
stack-prj.hierarchy> (derive ::positive-integer ::integer)
nil
stack-prj.hierarchy> (derive ::long ::integer)
nil
stack-prj.hierarchy> (lca ::positive-integer ::long)
:stack-prj.hierarchy/integer
```

Here's how it works: I take the set of ancestors of each type using `ancestors`. I add the type itself to the resulting set (since I think `(lca ::integer ::long)` should return `integer` instead of `decimal`) using `conj`, for both types. Using set intersection, I store *all* common ancestors into the variable `ac`.

Of the common ancestors, I want to know which one of those has the *most* ancestors. `(comp count ancestors)` is a function which takes one type and returns the number of ancestors it has. I partially apply `max-key` to this function, and then I apply (using `apply`) the resulting function to the collection `ac`. The result is the common ancestor with the greatest number of ancestors, or the *least common ancestor*.

(Note that `lca` will give an error if you pass it two types without any common ancestors! You should decide how to handle this case yourself.)

Comment: Thanks! Though `ancestors` should be probably wrapped in `set` to prevent `intersection` from throwing an error when provided with a list created by `conj`ing to nil when there are no ancestors.

Comment: Why do you use `into #{}` instead of `set`?

Comment: BTW, thanks for introducing me to `max-key`! I've been using Clojure for a couple of years but I haven't yet encountered this function.

Comment: I'm used to using `into` as my go-to function for converting one collection type to another. `set` works just as well in this case; it's just not my style.